# Eclipse / Java path problems

Tags: java, matlab

I'm currently following the third tutorial listed here: [here](http://www.mathworks.com/products/javabuilder/demos.html)
where I'm trying to compile some matlab code into Java classes.  Creating a project in eclipse, and correctly linking the libraries (exactly how its done in the tutorial).  Everything actually compiles, but when I run the program I get an Unsatisfied Link error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load library: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2009b\bin\win32\BuilderJABootstrap.dll
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.System.load(Unknown Source)
at com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.internal.MWMCR.<clinit>(MWMCR.java:1571)
at com.demo.DemoMCRFactory.<clinit>(DemoMCRFactory.java:100)
at com.demo.MLTestClass.<init>(MLTestClass.java:62)
at Driver.main(Driver.java:16)
```

The troubling part is the Can't load library: as the path provided '\win32' is not a legitimate path on my computer as I have a 64 bit machine, so the dll is located at \win64.  However, I've triple checked all my Environmental variables and am kind of stuck.  Could I be using a 64-bit version of matlab, with a 32-bit library?

Thanks!

Comment: This is going to sound dumb, but what if you copy the content of \win64 to \win32? Will that run at least?

Comment: interesting .... let me see ....
In the mean time:
http://www.mathworks.de/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/245729
is the same problem but occurred last year =/

Comment: Now I get this:
Can't load AMD 64-bit .dll on a IA 32-bit platform

Comment: I am running the 32-bit Java at this time, would this be the problem?

Comment: On it; will report how it goes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ChrisH's solution was it